# Tags label is cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When asking a question, the "Tags" label is cut off at the bottom. I'm using Version 1.1.0.117 with iOS 8 and iPhone 5.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug occurred as a result of some changes with AutoLayout on iOS8.

This will be fixed in the **next beta version** (1.1.0.118).